# Vertical alignment list

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I have a "list" that is composed by two entries per row. The two entries should be spaced but also aligned horizontally with each other (considering different rows). In picture an example of the problem I'm facing. I would like to not use table environment since it creates a space with the left margin

[image]

Comment: Have you tried preceding `tabular` (or `tabbing`) by `\noindent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `@{}` to the row of a tabular it removes the padding, so that could maybe be your solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent text text text

\noindent \begin{tabular}{@{} ll @{}}
$h$ & Specific hentalpy, J/kg \\
$e_f$ & Specific flow exergy, J/kg
\end{tabular}

\noindent text text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou very much, it works perfectly-